# how to patch bash vulnerability (shellshock) bug on RHEL?

Tags: linux, bash, patch, shellshock, bugzilla

We have over 10000 servers to patch for bash vulnerability (shellshock) bug. Now my question is what is the command to patch this bug ? And how we can check whether the patch has been installed and the bug has been fixed ?

Comment: According to Redhat [they've updated bash](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223#faq_six_CVE_assignments) to deal with this.  So install the updates.

Comment: @goldilocks: i need the proper command to patch this bug and after patching how we can know that the patch has been installed and bug has been fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to upgrade `bash` with `up2date bash` command on each servers, then execute [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wreiske/shellshocker/master/shellshock_test.sh) to test if all is OK. But if the upgrade is a success, I'm not sure testing is needed. [doc up2date](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/11236)

Comment: whether 'rpm -Uvh (new_bash_rpm_package name)' command will patch the vulnerable bash file ?

Comment: Yes, it's another possibility

Comment: +1. Because it should have at least 1! Your answer is completely correct whether it's a duplicate or not. You're also right that he/she shouldn't feel the need to have to test. Unless they're doing some strange experiment it's not really necessary. Of course terminating all the running bash processes would possibly be required (depending on if it was a shared library or not that was updated) but that should be all that's necessary.